# How to convert int to wide char?

Tags: c

When I use sprintf along with %lc and integer higher than 255, sprintf saves to string multiple 1 byte-characters (and it's just for one wide character). Example:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  char buf[200] = "\0";
  int wide_char = 500; // example
  sprintf(buf, "%lc test", wide_char);
  printf("%s\n", buf);
  printf("%d %d %d\n", (unsigned char)buf[0], (unsigned char)buf[1], (unsigned char)buf[2]);
  return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
Ǵ test
199 180 32
```

So the wide char with value 500 turns into 199 and 180. The binary format of those numbers is next:

```
       1 11110100 // 500
11000111 10110100 // 199 and 180 respectively
```

So my goal is to understand how to convert int to wide char and learn how to save manually wide char to string (like we can do it with regular char - buf[0] = 97).
I see some patterns, but can't understand.
Some more cases:

```
         10000000 // int = 128
11000010 10000000 // encoded to wide char

       1 10000001 // int = 385
11000110 10000001

      10 10000001 // int = 641
11001010 10000001

      11 10000001 // int = 897
11001110 10000001

       1 00000110 // int = 262
11000100 10000110
```

Comment: Note that `sizeof(wchar_t)` might be different from `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: And what is the reason you use `int` instead of `wchar_t`?

Comment: Oh and on an unrelated note, `char buf[200] = "\0";` is the same as `char buf[200] = { '\0', '\0' };`. You can just do `char buf[200] = "";` to create an empty string.

Comment: We can explain how a `%lc` conversion specifier instructs the `printf`-family functions to behave, but it's unclear to me whether that's what you mean by "convert int to wide char" or "save [...] wide char to string" or what the significance of "char - buf[0] = 97" is supposed to be.

Comment: note, that `500` == `000111 110100` and now look at 199, 180 - 11 **000111** 10 **110100** - this is how multibyte utf8 works

Comment: And a quite important note: The `%lc` format expects a value of type `wint_t`, while you're passing a value of type `int`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. And as before, there's no guarantee that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(wint_t)`.

Comment: It's encoding using UTF-8 (presumably due to having a UTF-8 locale).

Answer (score 0):

It's using the UTF-8 encoding (presumably due to having a UTF-8 locale).

If I just add some spaces every 6 bits, the pattern becomes clearer.

```
      10   000000 // int = 128
11000010 10000000 // encoded to wide char

     110   000001 // int = 385
11000110 10000001

    1010   000001 // int = 641
11001010 10000001

    1110   000001 // int = 897
11001110 10000001

     100   000110 // int = 262
11000100 10000110
```

The number of leading `1`s indicates the number of bytes in the pattern, so a leading `110` means it's a two-byte sequence, except that a leading `0` is used for a single-byte sequence. Bytes other than the first start with `10`.

Note that using `int` for `%lc` is incorrect. `%lc` expects a `wint_t`. This may or may not be equivalent to `int`. If it's not, your code has undefined behaviour.